# Cannot Delete UML diagram in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new to Intellij, I created an UML diagram for a class as below but didnt save it.
[image]

after closing the tab i could always see this file when i do double shift and search for files as below

[image]

Can someone tell me how to delete this UML diagram. as its bit irritating to see this all the time. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your UML-Diagram is saved as an `.uml` file. Closing the tab does not delete it.

To find the location of the file open it and click on **Select opened file**.
Its the "aiming" symbol in your Project-Tab.

[image]

Then delete the file when you found it.

[image]